# php check datetime from url

Tags: php

Date and time from URL shall be in format YYYY-MM-DD-HH-II-SS. I want to check it correctness and insert into database in column of mysql timestamp format.

1) With `$timestamp = $this->input->get('time_from')` I receive it from url.

2) Before insertion in database I try to print it.

```
 if (! empty($timestamp)) {
        $timestamp = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d-H-i-s', $timestamp);
        if (! $timestamp)
            echo date_format($timestamp, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
     }
```

3) I obtain that year could be before 1970, for example 1950-01-01-10-32-01 is correct by this checking. But it is impossible to insert such date in mysql column.
4) I obtain that 2012-02-31-10-00-00 is transformed automatically in 2012-03-02 10:00:00.

The questions are: how to avoid these confusing automatic transformations? What is the best way to provide such checking?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store a date before 1970 in a MySQL TIMESTAMP column. Use DATETIME instead. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

You can use the [checkdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function to see if a date is valid.

Comment: I don't need dates before 1970. I continue use TIMESTAMP. checkdate function also do not give possibility to check if it is satisfy mysql timestamp requirements.

Comment: If you look at the MySQL documentation I gave you a link to, you can see the date range that the Timestamp type allows and check against those. You can use checkmate to see if the date is valid - if it is not, it will be "transformed" as you describe in your #4.